# Adjust layout for frame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, layout, layout-manager

I want to set a specific layout for this frame, for 'accuracy, I would like the frame to be displayed in the center of the screen, I tried to enter the GridLayout (x, y), with specific coordinates, but it gives me warning in eclipse the only thing that i can do is to set the null layout,as below.

```
class Login extends JFrame {
/**
 * 
 */
      setTitle("Title");
      setLayout(null);
      .
      .
      .
```

Comment: What is your question?  And is it about the `JFrame` positioning on-screen, or the `JComponent` positioning inside it?

Comment: it is only about the jframe position on-screen.

Comment: i can' t put the grid layout, because eclipse give me warning.

Comment: `this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` should give you centre position

Comment: Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: No exception,no error, only on the left of eclipse the warning.

Comment: `<head-desk />`  Those comments come from *my* copy/paste comment utility!  They are kept deliberately short because I often collect 5 or more of them, hitting the limit for a comment.  You might extend that one as *"Always copy/paste error, exception **& warning** output."*.  Jeesh..  And a tip:  Add @boxed__l (or whoever, the `@` is important), to *notify* them of a new comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a warning shouldn't forbid you from compiling in most cases.
Second, you're misusing the constructor. Read the GridLayout docs - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want the frame to be displayed at the center of the screen, use `setLocationRelativeTo(null);`
GridLayout is not used to enter coordinates in terms of pixels but in terms of the grids you have created. If you want accurate positioning in pixels, set the layout to null, and then use `setBounds()` on any GUI component you wish.

For example:

```
    JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("Title");
    aLabel.setBounds(50, 50, 30, 10); //x, y, width, height
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the "setLocationRelativeTo(null);"? this should center the frame
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29